# maxscript transparent background (alpha)

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I need help to make transparent background via maxscript.
I know that its just one preperty from the Preferences->Rendering->Background->Use Environment Alpha.

I'm using vray 2.40 for render - so its V-Ray frame buffer

Here is my code:

```
f = "D:\\1.max"
    mergemaxfile f #select;
    renderFilename = getFilenameFile f + ".png";

    pngio.setAlpha true;
    pngio.setType #true48;
    rendOutputFilename = "D:\\"+renderFilename;
    rendsavefile = true;
    bm = render();
    bm.FileName = "D:\\"+renderFilename;
    save bm;

    delete selection;
```

So after this code i have a picture, but background is BLACK (from background color - environment)

But if i would save this render mannualy by my hands from frame buffer - the background would be transparent... how to solve this problem? i need transparennsy from script!(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in Vray Frame Buffer...
I've turned off "Enable built-in Frame Buffer" (render setup->V-Ray->V-RayLL Frame buffer) and now its all OK! SUDDENLY o_O

Comment: YOU SAVED MY ASS!!!!!!!!!!!!! I have been searching all night on why my background transparency wasn't working with V-Ray. I even created videos explaining my basic issue, feeling like a complete and utter dumbass. You, sir, have saved me on a time-sensitive project so thank you!